# Tkinter canvas image bug

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am rewriting my application in oop style and ran into an unexpected problem. The palette image is distorted. This has never happened before.

[image]

The class container

```
class MainApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, path):
        self.master = master
        Frame.__init__(self, self.master)

        self.configure_main()

        coloring = Coloring(self.master, path)
        coloring.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

The class from which the color selector instance is instantiated

```
class Coloring(Frame):  
    def __init__(self, parent, path):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self, self.parent)

        ...
        
        self.create_widgets()
        self.draw_widgets()
  
    def change_custom_color(self, *args):
        try:
            self.selector_frame.destroy()
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        self.selector_frame = ColorSelector(self.parent.master, args[1], self)
        self.selector_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

The color selector class

```
class ColorSelector(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, btn_idx, coloring_obj):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self, self.parent)

        self.btn_idx = btn_idx

        self.palette_img_np = cv2.imread('resources/palette.png')
        self.palette_img_tk = cv2pil_images(self.palette_img_np)

        self.coloring_obj = coloring_obj

        self.create_widgets()
        self.draw_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.palette = Canvas(self, width=253, height=253)
        self.palette.create_image(128, 3, anchor='n', image=self.palette_img_tk)
        self.palette.create_oval(5, 3, 251, 251, outline='black', width=4)
        self.cursor_obj_id = self.palette.create_oval(81, 81, 71, 71, fill='green', outline='white')
        self.palette.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda event, arg=self.btn_idx: self.cursor_move(event, arg))

        self.slider_explanation = Label(self, text='Color saturation:')

        self.enchance_var = IntVar(value=1.0)
        self.enhance_slider = Scale(
            self, from_=0.1, to=1.0, orient=HORIZONTAL,
            command=lambda event, arg=self.btn_idx: self.change_enhance(event, arg),
            resolution=0.0001, variable=self.enchance_var, length=200
        )

        self.ok_btn = Button(self, text='OK', command=self.destroy)

    def draw_widgets(self):
        self.palette.pack(padx=15)
        self.slider_explanation.pack()
        self.enhance_slider.pack()
        self.ok_btn.pack(pady=10)
```

Screenshot without bug
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not really about the question but when you wrote this: `lambda event, arg=self.btn_idx: self.cursor_move(event, arg)`, you can simplify it to `self.cursor_move` and use `self.btn_idx` instead of `arg` in your function.

Comment: Why are you using `cv2` to read image, use `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage()`.

Comment: The bug might come from `cv2` as @CoolCloud suggested. You might also want to check that the image (`"resources/palette.png"`) hasn't been corrupted.

Comment: I see no "distortion" in the sample screenshots. What part exactly are you talking about?

Comment: Should be like the below image. @martineau

Comment: From cv2 i am using thresholding, resizing, floodfill. cv2 is the main library in this project for working with images. But I'm in the process of deciding what to do with the fact that I have two libraries for working with images @Cool Cloud

Comment: Thanks, I will consider @TheLizzard

Comment: Process the image and save the image and load that new saved image with PIL maybe.

Comment: It helped thanks a lot! Maybe you could explain why a problem occurred? @Cool Cloud

Comment: What is `cv2pil_images()` is it a function you made?

Comment: def cv2pil_imgs(self, nparray):
        img = Image.fromarray(nparray)
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        return image
@Cool Cloud

Comment: Looks like you swapped blue and red channels somewhere. Usually happens when mixing OpenCV (which uses BGR by default) with other libraries that expect RGB by default, and forgetting to make appropriate conversions.

Comment: I have not used `cv2` much but I think there is `cvtColor` to change from one mode to another.

Comment: I tried, this is not the problem. But I am already very pleased with the help, further I can myself @CoolCloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be with the array conversion or something, it is recommended to load and use images using `PIL` itself, so its much easier. As a work around for you, you can use `cv2.imwrite()` and save the image and then use that path and open the new image up using `PIL`. Something like:

```
# All the other processes...
path = 'img1.png' 
cv2.imwrite(path)

img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file))
```

and use `img` as the image and so on.

This might be some bug with your array, as it is not reproducible for me, it works perfectly, anyway here is a function that I would use:

```
def cv2pil(array):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(array,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # Also try COLOR_BGR2RGBA for png?
    pil_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(img))
    return pil_img

img = cv2.imread('capture.png')
pil = cv2pil(img)
```

Except for the color modes switching I don't see any other distortion.